# Forma más limpia de cambiar nombres de DNS desde la terminal

Tags: linux, bash, debian, dns, networking

Sé algunas maneras para cambiar la dirección de los nombres de servidores del DNS.

Una es usando `resolvconf`:

```
$ sudo apt install resolvconf
$ sudo systemctl start resolvconf.service
```

Luego añadir algunas líneas al archivo `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`

Y luego reiniciar el servicio:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart resolvconf.service
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

**Problema**: El problema con esta aproximación es que el archivo `head`, en donde se añade la dirección de los DNS, indica que no se debe editar.

La otra es instalando `dnsmasq`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Editando el archivo `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
...
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
...
```

Y reiniciando los servicios:

```
$ sudo service dnsmasq restart 
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

**Problema**: Cuando corro `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, no encuentro las direcciones que añadí. Además, cuando hago un `dig google.com`, en la parte de `SERVER`, obtengo el valor de `127.0.0.1`, y no, ni las direcciones que añadí, pero tampoco las originales.

Por otro lado, **sé que no puedo editar el archivo** `/etc/resolv.conf`, ya que otros servicios lo sobrescriben.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera más "limpia" de cambiar las direcciones de DNS.

"Limpia", en el sentido de ver los resultados de la ruta del servidor DNS reflejados, pero sin tener que editar archivos en los cuales se indica que su edición no es recomendada.

Comment: No hay problema en usar `head`, de hecho la advertencia de edición que ves ahí es para que termine en el enlace simbólico de `/etc/resolv.conf`. Opcionalmente puedes editar `base` para tranquilidad de tu alma. Por cierto, cuando solamente editas head, base o tail no es necesario reinicar todo el servicio, es suficiente con `sudo resolvconf -u`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anduve preguntando a amigos y en foros de networking, y al final obtuve una respuesta relacionada com *systemd*.

Las especificaciones de mi equipo son:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
```

Cree esta máquina virtual utilizando la consola de google cloud.

En mi caso, la VM está utilizando el framework raro de `systemd` (que siempre me ha causado un buen de conflictos), y lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

1. Editar el archivo /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

   ```
   ...
   [Resolve]
   DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
   ...
   ```
2. Reemplazar el archivo `/etc/resolv.conf`:

   ```
   $ rm /etc/resolv.conf
   $ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
3. Reiniciar el servicio `sudo service systemd-resolved restart`

Y listo. Cuando corro, `systemd-resolve --status`, obtengo:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
             
...
```

Y cuando hago un `dig`, obtengo:

```
$ dig 127.0.0.1
...
;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 17 06:59:27 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
...
```

De esta manera logré modificar el DNS sin instalar ningun programa nuevo. Quizás si forcé un poco el asunto al modificar bruscamente el archivo `/etc/resolv.conf`.